# How to add controls in split container using for loop in windows form

Tags: c#, winforms

I am developing a windows application containing 3 split containers(two panels each, 
total 6 panels).
Now I want to add 3 labels dynamically in each panel.One solution I am trying to use for loop and access all splitcontainers and their panels but I dont know how to use for loop for accessing splitcontainer.
Can I use for loop for this? Also I want to add controls to all panels(6) at the same time. How to do this.
Thanks in advance..!!
This is what I have done...

```
foreach (SplitContainer sp in this.Controls)
        {          
            Label tileTitle = new Label();
            tileTitle.Text = "OneClick";
            tileTitle.Visible = true;
            tileTitle.Location = new Point(10, 10);
            sp.Panel1.Controls.Add(tileTitle);
        }
```

Comment: more details, please. where do you store your splitcontainers? directly on the form or in a container?

Answer (score 2):

```
foreach (Control c in this.Controls)
{
    if (c is SplitContainer)
    {
        Label tileTitle = new Label();
        tileTitle.Text = "OneClick";
        tileTitle.Visible = true;
        tileTitle.Location = new Point(10, 10);

        Label tileTitle2 = new Label();
        tileTitle2.Text = "OneClick";
        tileTitle2.Visible = true;
        tileTitle2.Location = new Point(10, 10);

        ((SplitContainer)c).Panel1.Controls.Add(tileTitle);
        ((SplitContainer)c).Panel2.Controls.Add((tileTitle2));
    }
}
```

Comment: but when I try to add titeTitle text to panel 2 the tileTitle2 text is overlapped though i change its location. I have solved the problem by taking one array of splitterPanels containing total 6 panels and then added controls to each panel in forloop. Is there any other way to do this?

Answer (score 1):

Try to use the Controls.OfType extension to get only the controls of SplitContainer type

```
foreach (SplitContainer sp in this.Controls.OfType<SplitContainer>())
{
    Label title = MakeLabel("OneClick", new Point(10, 10);
    sp.Panel1.Controls.Add(title);
    Label title1 = MakeLabel("OneClick", new Point(10, 10);
    sp.Panel2.Controls.Add(title1);
}

private Label MakeLabel(string caption, Point position)
{
    Label lbl = new Label();   
    lbl.Text = caption;   
    lbl.Location = position;   
    lbl.Visible = true;   
    return lbl;
}
```

**edit**
Steve, you add the same label to panel1 and panel2. i fixed the variable name in the add method of panel2.

Comment: Thanks but this is not working. control is not getting added in panel one.I have solved the problem by taking one array of splitterPanels containing total 6 panels and then added controls to each panel in forloop. Is there any other way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

i have done this in the same way as Steve did it, but i'm using a `TableLayoutPanel` to store all the splitcontainers, because you can add more than one `SplitContainer` with `Dockstyle.Fill` at the same time.

```
    private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        foreach (SplitContainer sc in this.tableLayoutPanel1.Controls.OfType<SplitContainer>())
        {
            Label title = MakeLabel("OneClick", new Point(10, 10));
            sc.Panel1.Controls.Add(title);
            Label title1 = MakeLabel("TwoClick", new Point(10, 10));
            sc.Panel2.Controls.Add(title1);
        }
    }

    private Label MakeLabel(string caption, Point position)
    {
        Label lbl = new Label();
        lbl.Text = caption;
        lbl.Location = position;
        lbl.Visible = true;
        return lbl;
    }
```

the solution works perfectly as seen here: http://imageshack.us/photo/my-images/838/splitcontainer.png/

Comment: don't forget to mark an answer as accepted, if it helps you to solve it. that can help other users to solve related problems. thanks.